# How to integrate Custom Intent Actions using DialogFlow for Android

Tags: android, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I want to perform custom action on my app whenever a [custom intent](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/custom-intents) is active using google assistant, do any one know how can I achieve this, I have searched a lot but didn't any article explaining this in detail.

Comment: Could you provide more details? It's your own application? It's Google Assisttant app, if so did you check [Dialogflow - Google Assistant](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations/aog) or you wanted something more similar to [Android chatbot with dialogflow](https://medium.com/@abhi007tyagi/android-chatbot-with-dialogflow-8c0dcc8d8018)? What exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to do some action based on custom intent in my own app, like if a custom intent happen I just want to navigate to a specific page based on some parameters coming from intent

Comment: There are some builtin integrations mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations) but if you dont want to use builtin you must create your own integration like mentioned in [API Integrations](API interactions)